# REDSHIFT: Change value in column based on a certain value in another column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=938ab56d96fd398bb42f8d222369fd99)**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR(255),
    customer VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO customers
(order_date, country, customer)
VALUES 
('2020-04-10', 'DE', 'user_01'),
('2020-04-11', 'DE', 'user_01'),
('2020-04-13', 'AT', 'user_01'),

('2020-04-20', 'AT', 'user_02'),
('2020-04-22', 'AT', 'user_02'),

('2020-05-19', 'DE', 'user_03'),

('2020-06-17', 'AT', 'user_04'),
('2020-06-23', 'AT', 'user_04'),
('2020-07-04', 'DE', 'user_04'),

('2020-08-19', 'NL', 'user_05'),
('2020-10-23', 'FR', 'user_05');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
order_date   |   customer  |      country     |  
-------------|-------------|------------------|--------------------------------
2020-04-10   |   user_01   |       DE         |        
2020-04-11   |   user_01   |       DE         |       
2020-04-13   |   user_01   |       DE         |  --> country changed to DE 
-------------|-------------|------------------|--------------------------------   
2020-04-20   |   user_02   |       AT         |        
2020-04-22   |   user_02   |       AT         |       
-------------|-------------|------------------|-------------------------------- 
2020-05-19   |   user_03   |       DE         |      
-------------|-------------|------------------|--------------------------------
2020-06-17   |   user_04   |       DE         |  --> country changed to DE 
2020-06-23   |   user_04   |       DE         |  --> country changed to DE
2020-07-04   |   user_04   |       DE         |     
-------------|-------------|------------------|--------------------------------
2020-08-19   |   user_05   |       NL         |     
2020-10-23   |   user_05   |       FR         |
```

---

In the above example it can happen that there is one customer that ordered both in `DE` and `AT`. 
For those customers I want to assign the country `DE` in the column `country` to each of their `order_dates`.

With reference to one of the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68078838/assign-a-certain-country-to-all-orders-of-a-user-if-the-user-placed-at-least-one) I tried to go with this:

```
SELECT
c.order_date AS order_date,
c.customer AS customer,

(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE c.country = 'DE') OVER (PARTITION BY c.customer) > 0
      THEN 'DE' ELSE c.country
      END) AS country
      
FROM customers c
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

However, in `redshift` the `FILTER` function is not available. 
How do I have to modify the query to make it also work in `redshift`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN c.country = 'DE' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY c.customer)
```

This uses a `CASE` expression ***inside*** the analytic function to apply the filtering.

- Anything that doesn't match the condition returns a `NULL`
- Aggregates effectively skip `NULL`

[DB Fiddle With Both Approaches](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0eb8451bb08c67b07735e65399f2142d)

Comment: Just for my own documentation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=345867bb6279955e8f22cbec2c7aa69e